# How to dynamically lookup embedded Mongoid documents?

Tags: mongoid

My models are:

```
class Cali
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :license_expire_date, :type => String
  field :license_issue_date, :type => String
  embeds_one :address
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :state, :type => String
  field :city, :type => String
  embedded_in :cali, :inverse_of => :address
end
```

When I use `@fields = Cali.fields.keys`, I get only the two fields (`expire_date`, `issue_date`). I don't get the address in the result. Is there a way that I could find what is embedded and the fields inside it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here'a how to get association metadata.

Mongoid::Relations::Reflections#reflect_on_all_associations - see http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/Reflections

Note that if you want to supply more than one macro as an argument to reflect_on_all_associations as currently written, the macros have to be args.
If you want to supply an array, it has to be splatted, e.g. *macros, as in the following test.

The following is for "the old API," so you should use the above instead.

Mongoid::Relations::ClassMethods::associations - see http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/ClassMethods:associations

test/unit/cali_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class CaliTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Cali.delete_all
  end

  test "mongoid fields" do
    address = Address.new(state: 'NJ', city: 'New Providence')
    cali = Cali.create(address: address)
    assert_equal(1, Cali.count)
    macros = [:has_one, :has_many, :belongs_to, :has_and_belongs_to_many, :embeds_one, :embeds_many, :embedded_in]
    puts "Cali.reflect_on_all_associations(*macros):#{Cali.reflect_on_all_associations(*macros).inspect}"
    puts "Address.reflect_on_all_associations(*macros):#{Address.reflect_on_all_associations(*macros).inspect}"
    #puts "Old API - Cali.associations:#{Cali.associations}"
    #puts "Old API - Address.associations:#{Address.associations}"
  end
end
```

test output

```
Run options: --name=test_mongoid_fields

# Running tests:

Cali.reflect_on_all_associations(*macros):[#<Mongoid::Relations::Metadata
class_name:           Address,
cyclic:               No,
dependent:            None,
inverse_of:           N/A,
key:                  address,
macro:                embeds_one,
name:                 address,
order:                nil,
polymorphic:          No,
relation:             Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::One,
setter:               address=,
versioned:            No>
]
Address.reflect_on_all_associations(*macros):[#<Mongoid::Relations::Metadata
class_name:           Cali,
cyclic:               No,
dependent:            None,
inverse_of:           address,
key:                  cali,
macro:                embedded_in,
name:                 cali,
order:                nil,
polymorphic:          No,
relation:             Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::In,
setter:               cali=,
versioned:            No>
]
.

Finished tests in 0.008605s, 116.2115 tests/s, 116.2115 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```